# Prove that transfinite hierarchy of Borel sets will eventually stabilize at some $\lambda < \omega_1$

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

> We define the transfinite hierarchy of Borel sets $\langle {\bf \Sigma}^0_\alpha, {\bf \Pi}^0_\alpha \rangle_{\alpha \in \rm{Ord}}$ as follows:
>
> $$\begin{aligned} &\begin{cases}
> {\bf \Sigma}^0_1 &= \{B \subseteq \mathbb R \mid B\text{ is open}\}\\
> {\bf \Pi}^0_1    &= \{B \subseteq \mathbb R \mid B\text{ is closed}\}\end{cases}\\
> &\begin{cases}
> {\bf \Sigma}^0_{\alpha + 1} &= \{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n \mid \forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in {\bf \Pi}^0_\alpha\}\\
> {\bf \Pi}^0_{\alpha + 1}    &= \{\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n \mid \forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in {\bf \Sigma}^0_\alpha\}\end{cases} \text{ for all ordinal } \alpha\\
> &\begin{cases}
> {\bf \Sigma}^0_\alpha &= \{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n \mid \forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in \bigcup^0_{\xi < \alpha}{\bf \Pi}^0_\xi\}\\
> {\bf \Pi}^0_\alpha    &= \{\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n \mid \forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in \bigcup^0_{\xi < \alpha}{\bf \Sigma}^0_\xi\}
> \end{cases} \text{ for all limit ordinal } \alpha \end{aligned}$$
>
> Prove that there exists $\lambda < \omega_1$ such that ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha + 1}$ for all $\alpha \ge \lambda$.

In below attempt, I successfully proved that there exist ordinals $\alpha,\beta,\gamma$ such that

$$\begin{cases}
{\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0\\
{\bf \Pi}_\beta^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\beta + 1}^0\\
{\bf \Pi}_\gamma^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\gamma + 1}^0
\end{cases}$$

Next, I try to prove that there exists ordinal $\delta$ such that ${\bf \Sigma}_\delta^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\delta+ 1}^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\delta^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\delta+ 1}$ by showing that $\forall \xi \ge \alpha:{\bf \Sigma}_\xi^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0$ and $\forall \xi \ge \beta:{\bf \Pi}_\xi^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\beta}^0$ and $\forall \xi > \gamma:{\bf \Sigma}_\xi^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\gamma}^0$. But I am stuck at this step.

Please shed me some light!

---

**My attempt:**

Lemma: ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Sigma}_\beta^0 \quad {\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Pi}_\beta^0 \quad {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Pi}_\beta^0 \quad {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Sigma}_\beta^0$ for all ordinals $\alpha < \beta$

It follows directly from our Lemma that $\begin{cases}
{\bf \Sigma}^0_\alpha &= \{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n \mid \forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in \bigcup^0_{\xi < \alpha}{\bf \Pi}^0_\xi\}\\
{\bf \Pi}^0_\alpha    &= \{\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n \mid \forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in \bigcup^0_{\xi < \alpha}{\bf \Sigma}^0_\xi\}
\end{cases}$ for all ordinal $\alpha > 1$.

Assume the contrary that there is no ordinal $\alpha$ such that ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0$. Then ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 \subsetneq {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0$ for all ordinal $\alpha$. Let $\Theta$ be the Hartogs number of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\Bbb R))$. We define a function $\phi:\Theta \to \mathcal P(\mathcal P(\Bbb R))$ by $\phi(\alpha)={\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0 - {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0$. Clearly, $\phi$ is injective, leading to a contradiction. Hence there exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0$. Similarly, there exists an ordinal $\beta$ such that ${\bf \Pi}_\beta^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\beta + 1}^0$ and ${\bf \Sigma}_{\gamma + 1}^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\gamma^0$.

Comment: Any reason for downvoting this question?

Comment: I don't think the result is true, I think each step in the hierarchy up to $\omega_1$ adds new Borel sets. $\lambda=\omega_1$ certainly works, but it's not $<\omega_1$. (I don't understand the downvote either)

Comment: Hi @Max, could you please get me some hints to prove that there exists ordinal $\delta$ such that ${\bf \Sigma}_\delta^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\delta+ 1}^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\delta^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\delta+ 1}$?

Comment: The claim as written is **false**: the Borel hierarchy goes all the way to $\omega_1$. Here's a quick explanation of why you might expect this to be true. Suppose $\lambda<\omega_1$ is a limit ordinal and for every $\alpha<\lambda$ there is an $X_\alpha\in\bf\Sigma^0_\alpha\setminus\Pi^0_\alpha$. Then let $(\alpha_i)_{i<\omega}$ be cofinal in $\lambda$ (since $\lambda<\omega_1$), let $Y_n$ by $X_{\alpha_n}$ "ported onto" the open interval $(n, n+1)$ (via some homeomorphism $\mathbb{R}\cong(n,n+1)$), and think about $Y=\bigcup_{n\in\omega} Y_n$. Of course that's not a proof, but it should help.

Comment: (As to why it stops at $\omega_1$: think about cofinality ...)

Comment: @NoahSchweber :  I was aware that it didn't stop before $\omega_1$ but I had never seen the heuristic you just gave, thank you for that !

Comment: Hi @NoahSchweber, from this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/312786/how-to-show-sigma-omega0-not-exhaust-the-borel-sets), it seems to me that to prove that each step in the hierarchy up to $\omega_1$ adds new Borel sets, we need some advanced knowledge about *universal sets*. Is there any elementary proof? (I am jut studying Introductory set theory).

Comment: Hi @NoahSchweber I have recently posted this question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124844/given-the-hierarchy-of-borel-sets-how-to-prove-that-bf-sigma-alpha0-sub), please have a look at it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a *much* simpler proof that the Borel hierarchy stabilizes at $\omega_1$ (and a slightly more complicated argument gives that it doesn't stabilize at any $\alpha < \omega_1$). Here's the outline:

Prove that, since $\mathrm{cof}(\omega_1) = \omega_1$, $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}_{\omega_1}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra, i.e. closed under complements and countable unions.

Now prove that if $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_{\alpha}$ is contained in a $\sigma$-algebra $\Sigma$, then $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_{\alpha+1} \subseteq \Sigma$ as well.

Conclude that $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_{\omega_1+1} = \boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_{\omega_1+1} = \boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_{\omega_1} = \boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_{\omega_1}$.

---

Let's now turn to the question whether it could stabilize at $\alpha < \omega_1$.

**Definition.** Let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$. For $y \in \mathbb{R}$ we let
$$
X_y := \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid (x,y) \in X \}
$$

**Definition.** Let $\alpha < \omega_1$. $U \subseteq \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ is *universally $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_{\alpha}$* if it is $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$ (as a subset of the Polish space $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ -- which is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$) and for every $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ which is $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$ there is some $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that
$$
X = U_y.
$$
Likewise for $\Pi^0_\alpha$.

**Lemma.** For every $\alpha < \omega_1$ there is some universally $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$ set $U$ and some universally $\boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_\alpha$ set $V$.

**Proof (Hint).** By an induction on $\alpha$. If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, pick $(\alpha_n \mid n < \omega)$ cofinal in $\alpha$ and use $y$ to code countable unions of elements that appear in $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_{\alpha_n}$ for some $n$.

**Lemma.** Let $\alpha < \omega$. Then $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_\alpha \neq \boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_\alpha$.

**Proof.** Let $U$ be universally $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_\alpha$. Let
$$
X =\{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid (x,x) \not \in U \}.
$$
Let
$$
\rho \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R \times \mathbb R, x \mapsto (x,x).
$$
$\rho$ is continuous and hence
$$
X = \{ x \in \mathbb{R} \mid \rho(x) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \setminus U \} = \rho^{1}[\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \setminus U]
$$
is $\boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_{\alpha}$. (Use that $\boldsymbol{\Pi}^0_{\alpha}$ is closed under continuous substitution and that $\mathbb{R}$ is homeomorhpic to $\mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$.)

By a diagonal argument, conclude that $X$ is not $\boldsymbol{\Sigma}^0_{\alpha}$. Q.E.D.

Comment: I am really grateful for your dedicated help @Stefan!

Comment: @LeAnhDung You're very welcome!

Comment: Bro, $\Bbb{R} $ can't be homeomorphic to $\Bbb{R}\times \Bbb{R}$, since removing one point would make the first guy disconnected but not the latter.

Answer (score 1):

After three days of thinking, I have figured out an *incomplete* proof and posted it here.

---

> **Lemma 1:** ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Sigma}_\beta^0 \quad {\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Pi}_\beta^0 \quad {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Pi}_\beta^0 \quad {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Sigma}_\beta^0$ for all ordinals $\alpha < \beta$

It follows directly from our **Lemma 1** that $\begin{cases}
{\bf \Sigma}^0_\alpha &= \{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n \mid \forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in \bigcup^0_{\xi < \alpha}{\bf \Pi}^0_\xi\}\\
{\bf \Pi}^0_\alpha    &= \{\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n \mid \forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in \bigcup^0_{\xi < \alpha}{\bf \Sigma}^0_\xi\}
\end{cases}$ for all ordinal $\alpha > 1$.

Assume the contrary that there is no ordinal $\alpha$ such that ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0$. Then ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 \subsetneq {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0$ for all ordinal $\alpha$. Let $\Theta$ be the Hartogs number of $\mathcal P(\mathcal P(\Bbb R))$. We define a function $\phi:\Theta \to \mathcal P(\mathcal P(\Bbb R))$ by $\phi(\alpha)={\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0 - {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0$. Clearly, $\phi$ is injective, leading to a contradiction. Hence there exists an ordinal $\alpha$ such that ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0$. Similarly, there exists an ordinal $\beta$ such that ${\bf \Pi}_\beta^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\beta + 1}^0$ and ${\bf \Sigma}_{\gamma + 1}^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\gamma^0$.

> **Lemma 2:** $B \in {\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 \implies \Bbb R-B \in {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0$ and $B \in {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 \implies \Bbb R-B \in {\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0$ for all ordinal $\alpha$.

The assertion is trivially true for $\alpha=1$.

Let it hold for $\alpha$. We have $B \in {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha+1}^0 \implies B=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n$ where $\forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in {\bf \Pi}^0_\alpha$ $\implies \Bbb R-B=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}(\Bbb R-B_n)$ where $\forall n \in \mathbb N: \Bbb R-B_n \in {\bf \Sigma}^0_\alpha$. Hence $\Bbb R-B \in {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha+1}^0$. Similarly, $B \in {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha+1}^0 \implies \Bbb R-B \in {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha+1}^0$.

Let it hold for all $\xi < \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal. We have $B \in {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0 \implies B=\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n$ where $\forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in \bigcup^0_{\xi < \alpha}{\bf \Pi}^0_\xi \implies \Bbb R-B=\bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N}(\Bbb R-B_n)$ where $\forall n \in \mathbb N:\Bbb R- B_n \in \bigcup^0_{\xi < \alpha}{\bf \Sigma}^0_\xi$. Hence $\Bbb R-B \in {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha}^0$. Similarly, $B \in {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha}^0 \implies \Bbb R-B \in {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0$.

As a consequence, $B \in {\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 \iff \Bbb R-B \in {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0$ for all ordinal $\alpha$.

> **Lemma 3:** ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_\beta^0 \iff {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\beta^0$.

- Case 1:$\Longrightarrow$

$B \in {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 \implies \Bbb R-B \in {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0 \implies \Bbb R-B \in {\bf \Sigma}_{\beta}^0 \implies \Bbb R-(\Bbb R-B) \in {\bf \Pi}_\beta^0 \implies B \in {\bf \Pi}_\beta^0$. Similarly, $B \in {\bf \Pi}_\beta^0 \implies B \in {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0$. Hence ${\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\beta^0$.

- Case 2:$\Longleftarrow$

The proof is similar to above reasoning.

> **Lemma 4:** ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0 \implies \forall \beta \ge \alpha: {\bf \Sigma}_\beta^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0$.

${\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0$ trivially holds.

Let ${\bf \Sigma}_\beta^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0$ holds. Then ${\bf \Pi}_{\beta+1}^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha+1}^0$ and thus ${\bf \Sigma}_{\beta+1}^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha+1}^0={\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0$.

Let ${\bf \Sigma}_\xi^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0$ holds for all $\alpha \le \xi <\beta$ where $\beta$ is a limit ordinal. It follows that ${\bf \Pi}_\xi^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha}^0$ holds for all $\alpha \le \xi <\beta$ and thus $\bigcup^0_{\xi < \beta}{\bf \Pi}^0_\xi=\bigcup^0_{\xi \le \alpha}{\bf \Pi}^0_\xi=\bigcup^0_{\xi < \alpha+1}{\bf \Pi}^0_\xi$. As a result, ${\bf \Sigma}^0_\beta =$ $\{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n \mid \forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in \bigcup^0_{\xi < \beta}{\bf \Pi}^0_\xi\} = \{\bigcup_{n \in \mathbb N}B_n \mid \forall n \in \mathbb N: B_n \in \bigcup^0_{\xi < \alpha +1}{\bf \Pi}^0_\xi\}={\bf \Sigma}^0_{\alpha + 1}.$

On the other hand, ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0$. Hence, ${\bf \Sigma}_\beta^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha}^0$.

> **Lemma 5:** ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0 \implies {\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0$.

First, ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0 \implies {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha+1}^0$.

Second, ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha +1}^0$ and ${\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha +1}^0$.

It follows that ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha +1}^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 \subseteq {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha +1}^0$. On the other hand, ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha + 1}^0$. Hence ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Pi}_{\alpha +1}^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Sigma}_{\alpha +1}^0$ and thus ${\bf \Sigma}_\alpha^0 = {\bf \Pi}_\alpha^0$.