# A possible typo in a proof about closure in textbook Introduction to Set Theory 3rd by Hrbacek and Jech

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation

My textbook *Introduction to Set Theory 3rd* by Hrbacek and Jech introduces the below theorem as well as its proof:

> [image]
>
> [image]

In the proof, there is a statement which I highlight in red color:

> If $\langle a_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \rangle$ is a sequence in $D$, then $\langle a_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \rangle \in C_\alpha$ for some $\alpha < \omega_1$

I would like to ask two questions regarding this statement:

1. Is it correct that "$\langle a_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \rangle$ is a sequence in $D$" means $\forall n \in \Bbb N:a_n \in D$?
2. I think $\langle a_n \mid n \in \Bbb N \rangle \in C_\alpha$ is a typo. Instead, it should be $\forall n \in \Bbb N:a_n \in C_\alpha$. Please confirm if my understanding is correct!

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Yes, yes.${}{}$

Comment: Thank you so much for your verification @AndrésE.Caicedo!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your interpretations are correct. However, I'm not sure I'd call this a typo: notation like "$(a_i)_{i\in I}\in X$" (and language like "a sequence in $X$") is a very common abuse of notation for "$\forall i\in I(a_i\in X)$." So I think Jech wrote what he wanted to, although it is slightly incorrect.

Comment: Dear Noah, please have a look at my question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124844/given-the-hierarchy-of-borel-sets-how-to-prove-that-bf-sigma-alpha0-sub)!