# Nontrivial Borel Sets

Tags: measure-theory, borel-sets

We are covering Measure Theory and the Borel Algebra $B(\mathbb{R})$ and I am trying to find a nontrivial example of a Borel Set. With the notions of $F_\sigma$ and $G_\delta$ sets, I am wondering if we can find a borel set which is not the countable union or countable intersection of $F_\sigma$ or $G_\delta$ sets.

Mainly, I want to know how "bad" can a set in $B(\mathbb{R})$ be?

Comment: Very. Constructing non Borel sets is nontrivial, and by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solovay_model, constructing non measurable sets requires AoC.

Comment: The situation is better described at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy but I don't have the ability to decipher much of what is written there.

Comment: @MrigankaBasuRoyChowdhury To be fair, the OP is asking about complicated *Borel* sets, and these exist provably in ZF alone. Indeed, ZF + a tiny fragment of choice proves that there are non-Borel sets, even providing an explicit example of such!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

*The relevant topic here is [**descriptive set theory**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descriptive_set_theory). The standard texts on the subject are [Moschovakis](https://www.math.ucla.edu/%7Eynm/lectures/dst2009/dst2009.pdf) and [Kechris](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9780387943749); I tend to prefer the latter, especially as a first introduction unless you're already dead-set on becoming a logician, but the former is freely available on the author's website.*

---

The class of Borel sets is *vastly* more complicated than that. The key point is the **Borel hierarchy** (and the fact that it doesn't collapse).

The finite levels of the Borel hierarchy are more or less what one would expect:

- A set is $\Sigma^0_1$ iff it is open, and a set is $\Pi^0_1$ iff it is closed.
- A set is $\Sigma^0_{n+1}$ iff it is the union of countably many $\Pi^0_n$ sets, and a set is $\Pi^0_{n+1}$ iff it is the intersection of countably many $\Sigma^0_n$ sets.

At this point it's a good exercise to check that a set is $\Sigma^0_n$ iff its complement is $\Pi^0_n$.

*This notation extends the "F/G" notation you're used to - for example, the $F_\sigma$ sets are exactly the $\Sigma^0_2$ sets, and the $G_\delta$ sets are exactly the $\Pi^0_2$ sets. As we go further you'll see why this notation is much better.*

It turns out that this hierarchy is nontrivial:

> $(*)\quad$ For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a $\Sigma^0_n$ set which is not $\Pi^0_n$ (and conversely).

This isn't easy to prove, though, and relies on the notion of a **universal set** for these complexity classes (see e.g. [this old answer of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3124844/given-the-hierarchy-of-borel-sets-how-to-prove-that-bf-sigma-alpha0-sub?rq=1) for a summary of this notion).

---

But it gets worse - there are Borel sets which are not $\Sigma^0_n$ or $\Pi^0_n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$! This follows quickly from $(*)$. Basically, for each $n\in\mathbb{N}$ let $A_n$ be a $\Sigma^0_{n+1}$ set which is not $\Sigma^0_n$ with $A_n\subseteq [2n, 2n+1]$ (note that $\mathbb{R}\cong (2n,2n+1)$), and let $$A=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N}}A_n.$$ If $A$ were $\Sigma^0_n$, then $A_n$ would also be $\Sigma^0_n$ (since the "pieces" of $A$ are "nicely separated"), which isn't the case.

So we need to keep going:

- A set is $\Sigma^0_\omega$ iff it is a union of countably many sets each of which is $\Pi^0_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$, and a set is $\Pi^0_\omega$ iff it is an intersection of countably many sets each of which is $\Sigma^0_n$ for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$.

[We can keep on going like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfinite_induction#Transfinite_recursion), and e.g. define $\Sigma^0_{\omega+17}$, $\Pi^0_{\omega\cdot 2+43}$, $\Sigma^0_{\omega^2+\omega+1}$, and so on. That is, we can define the Borel hierarchy through [the countable ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number). And it turns out that we need *all* of these:

> For every countable ordinal $\alpha$, there is a $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ set which is not $\Pi^0_\alpha$ (and conversely).

At the same time it's a good exercise to check that any countable union of sets, each of which is $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ for some countable $\alpha$, is also $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ for some countable $\alpha$. So we get:

> The Borel sets are exactly those sets which are $\Sigma^0_\alpha$ (or $\Pi^0_\alpha$) for some countable ordinal $\alpha$.

That is, the Borel hierarchy stops [at $\omega_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal). Note that we *can* define levels of the Borel hierarchy past the countable ordinals, the point is just that we don't get anything new: the pointclass $\Sigma^0_{\omega_1+17}$ is the same as the pointclass $\Sigma^0_{\omega_1}$. (A "pointclass" is basically a complexity class of sets of reals - "open," "closed," "$F_\sigma$," and so on are examples of pointclasses.)

Comment: Incidentally, you might be wondering about that superscript. There are indeed such things as $\Sigma^m_n$ sets for general $m$ and $n$, but they get quite complicated. Roughly speaking, you can think of them in terms of definability, with $n$ measuring the *number* of quantifiers in the definition of the set and $m$ measuring the *type* of quantifiers in the definition of the set, and $\Sigma$ corresponding to $\exists$ and $\Pi$ corresponding to $\forall$ as far as the first quantifier goes. But this is rather difficult to make precise, so let's ignore it for now.

Comment: So this hierarchy that you are describing is or is similar to repeatedly taking unions of intersections of unions of intersections, etc. a finite number of times. Then all borel sets can be written in this union of intersections of unions of intersections... ? Is that at least the main idea of it?

Comment: @AndrewShedlock "So this hierarchy that you are describing is or is similar to repeatedly taking unions of intersections of unions of intersections, etc. a finite number of times" No, not a **finite** number of times - that's the whole point of the second section of my answer! The Borel sets aren't exhausted until we continue through *all the countable ordinals*.

Comment: Ahhh, thank you for highlighting that!

Comment: I am confused about the following: you mention that $F_\sigma = \Sigma_2^0$. However, sets in $\Sigma_2^0$ are countable unions of $\Sigma_1^0$ (open) sets, but $F_\sigma$ is the collection of countable unions of closed sets. What have I misunderstood?

Comment: Yes, but in your answer, you write "[a] set is $\Sigma^0_{n+1}$ iff it is the union of countably many $\Sigma^0_n$ sets", hence my confusion.

Comment: @TheoreticalEconomist Whoops, good point! That's a nasty typo. Fixed!

Answer (score 3):

As an addendum to Noah Schweber's answer, here's a concrete example of a set that is in both $\Sigma_3^0$ and $\Pi_3^0$ (and hence in $\Delta_3^0$) but neither in $\Sigma_2^0$ nor in $\Pi_2^0$.  The set of all real numbers in $[0,1]$ whose base-$10$ representations contain (a) infinitely many $1$'s and (b) finitely many digits that are not in $\{1,2\}$.

Requirement (a) gives a set in $\Pi_2^0$ that is not in $\Sigma_2^0$, while requirement (b) gives a set in $\Sigma_2^0$ that is not in $\Pi_2^0$.  Finite unions and intersections of sets in $\Sigma_n^0$ and $\Pi_n^0$ produce sets that are provably in $\Delta_{n+1}^0 = \Sigma_{n+1}^0 \cap \Pi_{n+1}^0$.