# Is A Borel set either a $G_\delta$ or a $F_\sigma$?

Tags: borel-sets

On my lecture notes I read the following statement:

*A Borel set can be either a countable union of closed sets ($F_\sigma$) or a countable intersection of open sets ($G_\delta$)*

Does it mean, for example, that given a set $A \in B(X)$ (where $X$ is a topological space), $A$ is either $F_\sigma$ or $G_\delta$?

Thank you!

Comment: No, it does not. In general the Borel hierarchy is much more complicated than that: see the accepted answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3330141/nontrivial-borel-sets?rq=1) for more information and some references.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $E =([0,1]\cap \mathbb Q) \cup ([2,3] \setminus \mathbb Q))$. If this is a $G_{\delta}$ then intersecting with $(-1, 1.5)$ we see that $[0,1]\cap \mathbb Q$ is a $G_{\delta}$ but this is known to be false. Similarly, if $E$ is an $F_{\sigma}$ so is its intersection with $[1.5,4]$ which makes  $[2,3] \setminus \mathbb Q$ an $F_{\sigma}$ . This is again a contradiction.

Comment: Does it mean that the statement written in italic is wrong?

Comment: @JulianVené Yes, that is  a strange statement.

Comment: Ok! I'll contact the professor for further questions. Very thanks for your kindness. Have a good day!